# How to calculate the area between four different gps co-ordinates points in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a four different gps co-ordinates how to calculate area between them
using lat long values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SphericalUtil.computeArea` method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).